# SELECTING in two tables...

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables that I  want to use for viewing my reports which I can get after inputting a date.

Here are my tables: for customers - customer_date, lastname, firstname

for services - room_number, date_in, date_out

Here is my code now : it seems that it can't get any rows from my table

```
<?php 

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db('irm',$conn);

if(isset($_GET['Submit'])){

$customer_date = $_GET['customer_date'];
}

?>
<form method="get">
<table width="252" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="98">Choose Date:</td>
    <td width="144"><label>
  <input onclick="ds_sh(this);" name="customer_date" id="customer_date" readonly="readonly" style="cursor: text" />
</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></a></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>  

<form>
<?php

    $tryshow = "SELECT * FROM customers,services WHERE customer_date = '$customer_date' ";

    $result = @mysql_query($tryshow,$conn)
            or die("cannot view error query"); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print...";
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<table width="700" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="100">Customer Date:</td>
      <td width="100">Last Name</td>
      <td width="100">First Name</td>
      <td width="100">Room Number</td>
      <td width="100">Date In</td>
      <td width="100">Date Out</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["customer_date"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['room_number']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_in']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_out']; ?></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<?php }?>
</form>
```

With this I can get a report of any customer who checks in on that date.

I need some advice. Hope you can answer me soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to relate the two tables with a JOIN. Based on the information given, `customers.customer_date` to `services.date_in` seems to be the most likely candidate. This assumes that the date columns hold only a date and not a date/time.

Also notice that I'm not using `select *` in my query and neither should you. ;-)

```
SELECT c.customer_date, c.lastname, c.firstname,
       s.room_number, s.date_in, s.date_out
    FROM customers c
        INNER JOIN services s
            ON c.customer_date = s.date_in
    WHERE c.customer_date = '$customer_date'
```

Comment: +1 for removing `SELECT *` and a proper join. @renz: Be specific and precise about the data that you want. Your RDBMS will always perform and scale better when you specify the exact columns you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply. im making the changes now. thanks for the coding advice too. im still new but with constant reading and trying i know i can do much more. thanks again

Comment: @joe i have applied your query but still it cant get any rows?? :(

Comment: @renz: Are you sure you have data that satisfies the query?

Comment: @joe yes , if i remove the where clause it displays rows. hmmmm strange

Comment: @renz: Then your input date (`$customer_date`) is probably not in the correct format to match the format in the table.

Comment: @joe i guess not. im using a js that i found as a date picker. it functions normally at my add customers. i used it on this form. also i tried to manually put the exact values which i have a table. but still no luck,

Comment: is my     if(isset($_GET['Submit'])){

$customer_date = $_GET['customer_date'];
} code wrong ??

Comment: @renz: Sorry but that's beyond my area of expertise.

Comment: @joe thanks again i got it working now i just remove the isset tag, thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

You don't appear to have any fields in common between the two tables. How do you store fact that customer A was in room B on date C? To do an SQL join, the tables being joined have to have at least one field in common.

As well, instead of just saying `die("cannot view error query")`, which is utterly useless for debugging purposes, try doing `die(mysql_error()`, which will give you the exact reason the query failed.

As well, if the query DOES work, then you're outputting an entire HTML table for each row found. You should have the table headers and footers data OUTSIDE of the fetch loop.

Answer (score 1):

When your making query to database make sure your date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Mysql understand date in this format only so that you have to compare the date format in this format only.

your `$customer_date` should be in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, I'd change customer_date to something more meaningful such as "date_in." (It's a good thing when the names are predictable!)  You don't need to specify that it's the customer since it's in the customer table already.