# printing data from two tables

Tags: php, sql, join

So my objective was to print data from two into a standard table.

It should ideally display the name of the each distinct scholarship and its table with a list of all the students who applied for it. I m uncertain if my approach is correct.

Please help, i m trying to learn the basics. Thanks in advance.

```
 <?php 
include_once 'function.php';
connect();

?>
<html><body>

<?php

$query = "SELECT *
FROM entry, student_details 

WHERE entry.user_id=student_details.user_id";

//run query
$result = mysql_query($query);
// creating a table


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Student ID</th>
<th>Student Name</th>

</tr>";

//Print the record that matches the criteria of the query
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['s_name']
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['student_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['student_name' ] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
}
?>

</table>
<?php close() 
?>
</body></html>
```

the error i get is this  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line `echo "<tr>";`

Answer (score 1):

Parse error messages don't necessarily originate on the actual line number stated, but many times one line above, being this:

```
echo $row['s_name']
-------------------^
// missing semi-colon
```

You forgot to put an ending semi-colon at the end.

Modify it to look like this:

```
echo $row['s_name'];
-------------------^
```

Comment: thanks fred.. the error is out of the way..
but i cant see any data printed. Just the table headers

Comment: @user2897131 You're welcome. Try changing this `WHERE entry.user_id=student_details.user_id"` to `WHERE entry.user_id='student_details.user_id' "` see if that will kick in.

Comment: @user2897131 Another thing this, this `<?php close()` - is that a function inside one of your included files? It probably should also have a closing semi-colon like this, but not 100% sure `<?php close();`

Comment: yeah it lies in the included file.

Comment: @user2897131 Try `WHERE student_details='$user_id' ";` am unsure about your table structure though. You might need to use `JOIN` but to be honest, I am not very good with JOINs, but I have seen it often lately.

Comment: thanks for all the help @Fred-ii- 
:) i'll look through JOIN, hoping that'll help

Comment: @user2897131 You're welcome. Am pretty sure that JOIN will do it.

Comment: @user2897131 Have a look at this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/5185246/1415724 which will give you a pretty good idea on how to use `JOIN` and also look over to the right hand side of your screen, under **Related**, you might find some answers there as well. That's where I got the link from.

Comment: @user2897131 I appreciate the comment, my pleasure.

Comment: Wonder why this was downvoted. Oh well, they're merely numbers on a screen, no biggie.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['s_name'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['student_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['student_name' ] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: And, the syntax error being? I know where it is, but you haven't pointed out "where" the OP made the mistake. All you did was paste the OP's code.

Comment: The syntax error being there were too many opening and closing brackets. The code i posted is just after removing it